# How to select data from a sub query using laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel

The code below is not working.

```
$subQuery = DB::table('table1')->groupBy('col');

$data = DB::table($subQuery, 'sub')->get();
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is already functional. The only alternative (to make the same query) is to inline the `$subQuery` part.

```php
$subQuery = DB::table('table1')->groupBy('col');

$data = DB::table($subQuery, 'sub')->get();
```

Is the same as

```php
$data = DB::table(function ($sub) {
        $sub->from('table1')
            ->groupBy('col');
    }, 'sub')
    ->get();
```

or

```php
$data = DB::table(DB::table('table1')->groupBy('col'), 'sub')->get();
```